# Can LVM VG Contain PVs With Different Filesystem Types

Tags: filesystems, lvm

Assuming of course, that both filesystems support LVM functionality.

I originally thought yes, since this is an abstraction layer, but when googled couldn't find a direct confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a few things mixed up:

- PV -> physical volume -> usually harddisks or arrays[1]
- VG -> volume groups -> a pool of one or more PVs put together
- LV -> logical volumes -> a subset of a VG, exported by LVM

So far you don't have any filesystem at all, especially PVs do not contain full filesystems [2]

Once you have LV, you treat it like a harddisk and create a filesystem on it. For the filesystem layer it doesn't matter if it gets created on a blank disk, a partition, a LV, a RAID or in RAM.

So yes, any filesystem, that can be created on a harddisk can be created on a LV [3], as many different as you want.

[1] in technical terms: *blockdevice*

[2] in reality they of course contain the data and therefore parts of the filesystem

[3] some filesystems are specialized, so performance and featureset might depend on the underlying device

Answer (score 0):

Actually the filesystem is created at the logical volume (LV) level, not at the physical volume one.

Physical Volumes are added to Volume Groups, and from there, you can create Logical Volumes inside that Volume Group. After that, you make a filesystem over that logical volume.